# Display database value in array PHP MYSQLi

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I"m attempting to display some data I've sent from ajax to a php file, however for some reason its not displaying it on the page. The way it works it I enter a search term into a input field, and a ajax script post the value to a php script, which return the database value requested back.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');


if (isset($_POST['name']) === true && empty($_POST['name']) === false) {
    //require '../db/connect.php';

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","retail_management_db"); 
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,trim($_POST['name']));    
    $query = "SELECT `names`.`location` FROM `names` WHERE`names`.`name` = {$name}";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $loc = $row['location'];
             echo $loc;   
        }//close While loop                            
    } else {
        echo $name . "Name not Found";
    }
}
```

html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Retail Management Application</title>
    </head> 
    <body>             
        Name: <input type="text" id="name">
         <input type="submit" id="name-submit" value="Grab">
            <div id="name-data"></div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/global.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are is the response you are getting from the AJAX call?

Comment: You have `mysqli_error()` in you query stiring. it should be - `query = mysqli_query("SELECT \`names\`.\`location\` FROM \`names\` WHERE \`names\`.\`name\` = {$name}" ) or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: Chip Dean, im getting Name not found!

Comment: and then you are doing a query on your previous query `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);`, which is really `$result = mysqli_query($con, mysqli_query("SELECT `names`.`location` FROM `names` WHERE`names`.`name` = {$name}" . mysqli_error($con)); );`.

Comment: Sean now i simply get a blank screen.

Comment: if you get a blank screen, you have some errors in your code. Turn on error reporting by placing `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your code.

Comment: It shows this:  br /> <b>Warning</b>: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ajax/name.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br /> <br /> <b>Warning</b>: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ajax/name.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />

Comment: `$name = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']));` needs to be after your `$con = mysqli_connect(...)` as it needs the `$con` as the 1st parameter - `$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($_POST['name']));`

Comment: ive done that but for mysqli_num_row it still complains with 
<br /> <b>Warning</b>: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ajax/name.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />

Comment: Then your query failed, which would cause the boolean. check your `mysqli_error($con)`. Also, update your answer with your edited code.

Comment: `if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {` to `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {`

Comment: then do `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));` to see why your query failed.

Comment: wait a minute you're querying twice using `mysqli_query()` that's the problem here. `$query = mysqli_query("SELECT` and `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);` you need to remove one. Did you not update your code with scrowler's?

Comment: Ive Updated the code like you ask Fred.

Comment: `$name` is a string, so it needs to be quoted - `... WHERE \`names\`.\`name\` = '{$name}'"`

Comment: Ive managed to fix it and yes @Sean that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending a MySQL error result to your query, and you're trying to query a query result, try the following:

```
$query = "SELECT `names`.`location` FROM `names` WHERE`names`.`name` = '$name'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

---

Edit:

`{$name}` that is a string and should be quoted instead.

change it to `'$name'` in the `where` clause.

Using:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

will provide you with the reason as to why your query failed.

Comment: Hi scrowler, ive made the changes but it seems it still says Name not found even though the records exists in the database.

Comment: Have you debugged `$_POST` in your PHP file to ensure that the value for `$name` is being correctly passed through?

Comment: Yh it shows this: br /> <b>Warning</b>: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ajax/name.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br /> <br /> <b>Warning</b>: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ajax/name.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />

Comment: Yeah - [check the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) - the first parameter needs to be `$con` (also implying you'd need to swap the lines around so that line comes *after* the line you're defining `$con`

Comment: It seems mysqli_num_rows still has errors:
<br /> <b>Warning</b>: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ajax/name.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />

Comment: scrowler's answer should be working or your query failed. As noted in comments, do `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));` @YacubAli to find out why.

Comment: ive got this error "Unknown column 'Yacub' in 'where clause'" @Fred-ii-

Comment: @YacubAli someone in comments noted about `{$name}` that should read as `'{$name}'` either that or just do `'$name'` or `'".$name."'` in your `where` clause. that's the most likely reason now.

Comment: @YacubAli you're welcome, glad to have been of help, *cheers*